# Unknown mathematical notation

Tags: notation

I'm reading a patent document with the following mathematical notation:

```
P.sub.V(S4)
```

Does anyone recognise this notation? I would like to convert this to a more readable format. The patent document has a lot of formulas. The notation above is easy to understand, but some of the formulas get quite bloated.

Here's another formula:

```
W.sub.1 + W.sub.2 + W.sub.3 + W.sub.4 = W.sub.TOTAL
```

sub obviously means subscript.

Comment: This is off-topic here. You may want to try on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)..

Comment: Hi there, thanks, I did that and they directed me here... I thought it might be some sort of notation to show formulas in something like latex.

Comment: Does the patent you are referring to have anything to do with programming?, because - as I read it - your question doesn't appear to.